# Process id not showing

Tags: python, process, subprocess

When I open the file with the following code

```
p = subprocess.Popen(fileName, shell=True)
```

We have 2 cases here, In second case my application is working fine. But in the first case behaving improperly.

In one machine, this process id is there until and unless that process is closed.

In other machine after opening the file, this process id is closed.

When I check with the process id in both cases with the following command:

```
psutil.pid_exists(processId)
```

In first case after opening the file, when I check with the process id it returns `True`. When we close the file or the process it will return as `False`.

In second case after opening the file, when I check with the process id it returns `False`.

Comment: Which file do you say is opened, and how do you know?  Did you check the exit code `p.returncode`?  Are you doing a `p.wait()`?  If you are not, then the parent might be exiting before the child has completed.

Comment: Why are you using `shell=True`? It's inadvisable in nigh-but-all circumstances.

Comment: Processes and files are two different things. A process does not close. You don't open files with `Popen`.

Comment: @Veedrac: on Windows, using `shell=True` is a QAD way of getting filename association, e.g. `.py` -> `python`.

Comment: I am opening this in thread, and wants to listen to the changes, edit in the file. Thats why i am opening in process. How i handle this situation, as subprocess.call is not blocking. and comes to the next command